# How do I refresh a list view from client side?

Tags: list-view, refresh

I have a list that doesn't immediately reflect changes after an item has been added to it. I'd like to be able to refresh it client-side as I don't have access to the code-behind but I can add HTML/Javascript as I please.

Is there any way to do that? I'm running SP 2007.

Comment: is there a workflow attached to the list ?

Comment: @Steve, No but I could add one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy out-of-the-box solution provided with SharePoint 2010: enable [asynchronous refresh in the web part properties](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/little-sharepoint-2010-gem-ajax-options-in-list-view-web-parts.aspx).

For SharePoint 2007, you can develop your own solution. I recommend using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) for that, and [here's a starting point](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2010/04/12/using-jquery-and-spservices-to-display-list-items.aspx). However it will be very hard to keep all of the same functionality provided in the UI so you will need to set user expectations here.

You could also try third party options. A web search for AJAX list web parts turned up the following (I haven't tested any of these):

- [AJAX SharePoint List Rotator Web Part](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/ajax-sharepoint-list-rotator-webpart/)
- [Virto AJAX List Form Extender](http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint-list-form-extender.aspx#2)
- [Telerik List View Web Part](http://www.telerik.com/products/sharepoint/aspnet-ajax.aspx#Listview)

Answer (score -1):

ListVieW WebParts do not have this option out of the box SP2010